# When a tag is added to an old question, the question is updated?

Tags: support, tags, answers

I want to add new tags to some old questions.

Will the question will show up in `Top Questions` `active` as it has an updated answer?

Comment: Long story short yes, any edit will bump the post to homepage/recently active page.

Comment: @Jenayah So, it is part of 2. `Editing the question or`

Comment: Yeah, by post I meant "same thread of question and its answers"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing the tags on a question is the same as editing and will cause the question to be bumped to the top of the [Questions/Active](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active) page with a link to the question. It will only show up on the [Home/Active](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=active) (i.e. the "Top Questions" active page) page if the question has a score of at least -3 (on main sites) or -8 (on metas, including this one, IIRC).